# Magento Using Composer Class in Module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, composer, geoip

I am using `geoip2/geoip2:~2.0` but need to access the **GeoIP** data from within a magento Model Class.

`use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;` gives an error. I am not sure how to call this in order to be able to use GeoIP.

I know the answer will be easy but 2 hours of Google has not helped.

** Edit **
My module sets the currency based on the geo location, it extends `Mage_Core_Model_Store`

```
class Module_Currency_Model_Store extends Mage_Core_Model_Store
{

    public function getDefaultCurrencyCode()
    {
```

The current code uses a server variable `$_SERVER["GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE"]`

I would like to replace with the composer install of GeoIP.

This requires the following code:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

$reader = new Reader($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/geoip/GeoLite2-Country_20171205/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb');
$record = $reader->country( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );


$country_iso_code = $record->country->isoCode ;
```

The autoloader is called in `Mage.php` so I don't think this is needed, but I cannot use

`use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;`

I don't know how to call this from within the class file.

** EDIT **
Old and new broken code requiring the USE statement
https://bitbucket.org/solvemyproblem/testmodule_currency/overview

Comment: would you mind sharing an example of how you're attempting to use the Reader, as well as the error message that you're getting?

Comment: I have edited the original question, thanks

Comment: "_Gives an error_" - which one?

Comment: If I place it in the public function i get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in"

If I place it in the class "Module_Currency_Model_Store cannot use GeoIp2\Database\Reader - it is not a trait"

Comment: I have just uploaded the full source files as that may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
<?php

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GeoIp2\Database\Reader;

class Testmodule_Currency_Model_Store extends Mage_Core_Model_Store {

    public function getDefaultCurrencyCode() {

        $reader = new Reader($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'vendor/GeoLite2-Country_20171205/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb');
        $record = $reader->country($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

        var_dump($record->country->isoCode); die;
        // or do something else...

    }
}
```

Just take care that your GeoLite2-Country.mmdb file is available at the given location (in this case `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'vendor/GeoLite2-Country_20171205/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb'`).

Comment: I swear I had tried that!

Thank's :) I spent far too long on that, next time it's late an I am tired I will goto sleep

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the composer autoloader (vendor/autoload.php) and register it before the Magento autoloader. That's important because the Magento autoloader will try to include the file where it expects the class to be which throws an error if that file does not exist. So later autoloaders do not have a chance at all.

There are some open source extensions that can do that for you, I can recommend https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Magento-PSR-0-Autoloader

## Configuration as per README:

> ### Magento Composer Autoloader
>
> You can also use this Extension to add the composer Autoloader.
>
> You need to configure the Path to your Vendor directory in your
> `<global/>`-node of local.xml:
>
> ```
> <composer_vendor_path><![CDATA[{{root_dir}}/vendor]]></composer_vendor_path>
> ```